# How to get the position of tableviewcell after scrolling the tableview

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, scroll

I want to get the position of UITableVIewCell relative to the screen, not relative to tableview. So, if I scroll the tableview, the position is updated.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking, because you did not specify (1) at what time you wish to get the position, (2) the position of what part of the cell you would like to get, and (3) should the display orientation play any part in the answer that you wish to get.

Comment: In general, when you are trying to do something that looks hard to achieve, the probability that you are doing something wrong is very high. You may get a better chance to have you problem resolved if you explain the actual problem that you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use two steps to achieve this:

1. Get the *CGRect* information for a selected cell/header or footer by using one of these methods of *UITableView*:

> ```
> - (CGRect)rectForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
> - (CGRect)rectForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section;
> - (CGRect)rectForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
> ```
>
> 2. Convert the *CGRect* to table's container view by using *UITableView*'s *convertRect* method. Eg. to get the current pos of the first header you can use this code:

```
    CGRect rect = [mytable convertRect:[mytable rectForHeaderInSection:0] toView:[mytable superview]];
```

If you want these above dinamically you might want to include this code in UITableView's delegate method:

```
  - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView_ {.....
```

One example what I've done using similar techniques is at github - how to make table header row fixed:

https://github.com/codedad/SO_Fixed_TableHeader_iOS

Hope it helps you!

Comment: This doesn't appear to take into account the contentOffset. If in didScroll method I log the rect of a particular cell, it doesn't change as I scroll

Answer (score 0):

You need to get position from child to parent:

```
float x = cell.frame.origin.x;
float y = cell.frame.origin.y;

UIView* parent = cell.parent;

while(parent != nil)
{
    x += parent.frame.origin.x;
    y += parent.frame.origin.y;
    parent = parent.parent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-[UITableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:]` method. Keep in mind that if you attempt to get this when the cell is off screen you will get unexpected results. You can then convert it to your view controller's view (which i think is what you mean by screen) with the `-[UIView convertRect:toView:]` method.

Ref: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_49

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#jumpTo_65